# Jolt: split/ concat array values in Nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I'm struggling with transformation using JOLT in Nifi

My input

```json
[
  {
    "value0": 0,
    "value1": 1,
    "value2": 2
  },
  {
    "value0": 3,
    "value1": 4,
    "value2": 5
  }
]
```

Desired Output:

```json
[
  {
    "val": 0
  },
  {
    "val": 1
  },
  {
    "val": 2
  },
  {
    "val": 3
  },
  {
    "val": 4
  },
  {
    "val": 5
  }
]
```

I almost managed to get it to work. Here is my (wrong) Jolt Spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "value*": "[&1].val"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Here is my result:

```json
[
  {
    "val": [ 0, 1, 2 ]
  },
  {
    "val":[ 3, 4, 5 ]
  }
]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "value*": "[].val"
      }
    }
}]
```

Comment: Thank you ! What if I'd like to replicate a value in each split ? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61416100/jolt-concat-array-values

Answer (score 0):

You can loop **2** * **3** = **6** times through successively nesting two layers by

```json
"*": {
  "*": {
  }
}
```

such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // loops twice through objects of the array 
        "*": { // loops three times for each attribute
          "@": "&2[#2].val"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the keys and square brackets
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```