# Jolt: concat Array values

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Following my previous post
[Jolt: split/ concat array values in Nifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61387418/jolt-split-concat-array-values-in-nifi)

Now I'd like another value (**`ts`**) to be replicated into each split.
My input:

```json
[
  {
    "value0": 0,
    "value1": 1,
    "value2": 2,
    "ts": 1
  },
  {
    "value0": 3,
    "value1": 4,
    "value2": 5,
    "ts": 2
  }
]
```

Desired output:

```json
[
  {
    "value0": 0,
    "ts": 1
  },
  {
    "value1": 1,
    "ts": 1
  },
  {
    "value2": 2,
    "ts": 1
  },
  {
    "value0": 3,
    "ts": 2
  },
  {
    "value1": 4,
    "ts": 2
  },
  {
    "value2": 5,
    "ts": 2
  }
]
```

The initial Jolt:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "value*": "[].&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Thanks !

Comment: It looks like this case is too complex for Jolt...

Comment: Hi dams. No, you can solve it by Jolt.

Answer (score 0):

At the max you could do this, beyond this to achieve the above will be very tricky, using some chained spec it might be possible.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "value*": "[].&",
        "ts": "[].&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Output for above spec:

```
[ {
  "ts" : 1
}, {
  "value0" : 0
}, {
  "value1" : 1
}, {
  "value2" : 2
}, {
  "ts" : 2
}, {
  "value0" : 3
}, {
  "value1" : 4
}, {
  "value2" : 5
} ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the attributes which starts with the literal **`value`** twice due to the fact that they're stated within the two objects of the array, while importing value of **`ts`** attribute from one level upper such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // loops twice through objects of the array 
        "value*": { // loops three times for each attribute
          "@": "&2[#2].&",
          "@1,ts": "&2[#2].ts"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the keys and square brackets
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]